# Unsure of how to go about this query. Dunno what to call this type of query either please correct this title! 

Tags: sql, ms-access, sorting, ms-access-2003

This query is supposed to run with ms access 2003 using SQL. the function JOIN is NOT supported explicitly.  implicitly in the WHERE clause is fine...implicity anywhere is fine as long as the word JOIN INNER JOIN Etc is not used.

```
     DayNumnber   PastTime
               .
               .
               .

       333           Homework
       333           TV
       334           Date
       620           Chores
       620           Date
       620           Homework
       725           Chores
       725           Date
       888           Internet
       888           TV
                  .
                  .
                  .
```

Hey I would like a query that can Show the most important past time done for each day (TV and internet do not count!) .So importance would be Homework > Chores > Date.So:

```
       DayNumber     PastTime
         333           Homework
         334           Date
         620           Homework
         725           Chores
```

Something that might change this problem.  Altho all the different past times are listen in a table together. but that was because i appended the table. originally the homework entries. chore entries and date entriess . internet entriess. tv entries. came from different tables.

```
 eg     homework 333
        homework 620
```

Is it easier to do it without appending these tables first? I would hopefully like it to be done with the appended table but ya

I was thinking of a mixture of insert. delete...  but the hardest part is checking that there is something there for a date a few things and how to put the more important thing done that day . Thank you

Comment: Homework? There's a "Homework" tag that might bring you more help.

Comment: Your first paragraph suggests you believe Access 2003 SQL won't support JOIN statements.  Is that your belief, or did I misinterpret what you said? It does support INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, and RIGHT JOIN.

Comment: @HansUp u read right i thought it supported it but then whenever i used join explicitly actually sayign the word join it wioll give me an error mesasge saying join format not supported or was it expression or funciton not supported i dotn quite remeber one of those . I'm not sure if its just the version i have at work or i unno =/ would actually really like to kno o.o

Comment: @Catcall thanks for the suggestion its not acutally hoemwork tho lol

Comment: If you, @Chaostryder , are also Stack Overflow users Lizzy and Lizzy Chow, I think the confusion may have stemmed from one of your previous questions.  The JOIN didn't work, but not because Access doesn't support joins.  Rather there was another problem with the specific SQL statement you tried as a join.  Don't give up on join!  Submit another question with a simple specific example of join not working for you, and we can probably figure out why.

Comment: Have you tried creating the JOINs in the Access Query Designer? It will get the syntax correct for you and then you can take the SQL and do with it what you want (as long as you leave the JOIN syntax alone).

Comment: @HansUp  alright thanks for being supportive . i will right after i get my other work done i have made progress in these past two days

Comment: @ David-W-Fenton lol i started doing access work for first time in my life about ... two days ago >.> and surprisingly ive learnt to udnertand SQL better than when the query is in design vie. I'm still not very used to the logic done that way. but ur right it wouldve fixed the join without me having to do anythign with the SQL and what not . i think this is what ur talking about right?

Comment: Yes -- start with the QBE in Access. You often can't get all the way to your desired end result, but at least you'll start out with SQL that you know has the right syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another table with:

```
Pri | PastTime
--------------
  1 | Homework
  2 | Chores
  3 | Date
```

This is a priority list for the items.

Next do:

```
  SELECT MIN(Pri), DayNumber
    FROM PastTime_table, Priority_table
   WHERE PastTime_table.PastTime = Priority_table.PastTime
GROUP BY DayNumber
```

This will give you the most important past time for each day. And because TV and Internet are not listed they will not show up.

But it will give you a number, and not the name.

If you had a better SQL you could then join this back to the Priority_table and lookup the name. But I guess you will have to do that part manually.

If you are willing to change the name and call them:

```
A_Homework
B_Chores
C_Date
```

instead then you could do (without any extra table):

```
  SELECT MIN(PastTime), DayNumber
    FROM PastTime_table
GROUP BY DayNumber
```

Since it sorts the name alphabetically it will always give you the best one.

You can add a `WHERE` to remove TV and Internet.